# How to send Ionic push notification through curl or terminal?

Tags: curl, push-notification, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications

In https://apps.ionic.io, I discovered 'curl' can be used to send a notification to android and iOS.

Later, I realised that if I have device token, I just to go terminal and copy&paste the 'curl code' that I got from 'apps.ionic.io' and just replace device token.

Android working fine with this way. I could see the notification is working.

But iOS, even though I know my iOS device token, and using a same way to send notification, it does not work.

Now I am using [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) for notification.
Still android is working but iOS is not working.

Is there something I am missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am having same issue...   can you confirm that you are actually getting a Token on REGISTER?

If not...  code snippet to get a clue about if PhoneGap is loading...
app.componenet.ts
      constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, public push: Push) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
          // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
          // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

```
     //  vy added this...

        alert('---  ABOUT TO DO PUSH TOKEN CODE  -----');
        console.log('=== About to look for TOKEN');
        this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
          //  This never happens... never gets to this point in the code.
          console.log('=== About to return TOKEN');
          return this.push.saveToken(t);
        }).then((t: PushToken) => {
          console.log('VY***********************************************'); 
          console.log('=== About to SAVE TOKEN');
          console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
          window.localStorage.setItem("deviceToken", t.token);          
          console.log('VY***********************************************'); 
        }).catch(function(error){  
          alert('----error----' + error  );
          console.log('error-----', error);
          console.error(error);});

        this.push.rx.notification()
          .subscribe((msg) => {
            alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
          });


// =============================
```

What do you curl commands look like...
This is what I have working for android... but also does not work for iOS.

curl -u PRIVATE_API_KEY: -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Ionic-Application-Id: 2bxxxc3c " https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push162 -d '{"tokens":["df902aff9cf46xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx092da76dfcb5a7fd5482e4d7e51b051f0
"],"notification":{"alert":"I come from planet Ion."}}'